# Make a checker board of 3x3 squares, asking the user for its width and height in asterisks

Tags: c++

I have this assignment:

> Write a program checkerboard3x3.cpp that asks the user to input width and >height and prints a checkerboard of 3-by-3 squares. (It should work even if >the input dimensions are not a multiple of three.)

*Example 1:*

```
Input width: 16
Input height: 11

Shape:
***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***
   ***   ***   *
   ***   ***   *
   ***   ***   *
***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***
   ***   ***   *
   ***   ***   *
```

*Example 2:*

```
Input width: 27
Input height: 27

Shape:
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***   
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
***   ***   ***   ***   ***
```

I don't know how I can get the program to understand that type of matrix. 
So far all I can get is a checkered patter of one * then a space and so forth. I need it to print three *'s then three spaces

Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{    

int height, width;

cout << "enter width" << endl;
cin >> width;

cout << "enter height" << endl;
cin >> height;

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) { 

for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {  
     if( ? ){
                    cout << "*";
                }else{
                    cout << " ";
                }

}
    cout << endl;
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to shift variable definitions to the point at which they're used. `for (int i; ...)` instead of declaring `int i` earlier without context.

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll fix that now, I'm new to C++ haha

Comment: Just a minor thing, but it helps. Remember in C++ one of the biggest risks is using uninitialized variables, so declaring them in their initialized form makes mistakes a lot less likely. Another thing that's important is consistent indentation. This helps express your intent more clearly and can often reveal mistakes.

Comment: Figure out how many rows of squares will fit, make that the outer loop.  Figure out how many columns will fit, make that an inner loop.  Figure out what you need to do to make 3 rows instead of just 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## HINT #1

The terminal will output a row at a time, so all you need to do is focus on outputting that single row. There are only two types of rows, let's call them a regular row and an offset row.

How do you know which type of row you'll be outputting based on the row number (`i`)?

#### Hint #1A

If you were alternating every other row, how could you assign to a boolean variable `isOffset` given the row number `i`? Now assume you were alternating every second row? Now step it up to what you're actually doing (every third row).

## Hint #2

If you know what kind of row you're outputting, everything should be easier. You can have two sets of logic for the two different kind of rows. Now, given a column, what kind of character are you printing?

The terminal will output a column character at a time, so all you need to do is focus on outputting the correct character. There are only two types of characters, let's call them a star character and a space character (sound familiar? And these are alternating every 3 too! The logic should look very similar).

Comment: I don't understand, I know I should have two sets of logic to get both acol and row identifier, but I don't know how to get there? Another For loop? I just started C++ not too long ago for school so I'm not great

Comment: If you have `i` rows and `j` columns, you'll be outputting `i * j` characters. Your nested loops you have setup will run a total of `i * j` times, so you're fine with those loops. The logic I'm trying to push you towards is what you'll write inside of the innermost loop. Every loop (given the way I'm steering you towards), you'll output exactly 1 character. The question then becomes...which one?

Comment: I DID IT, only took me all day. haha I ended up using some (probably inefficient) if statement using mod %. ' if ( (j % 6 == 0 || j % 6 == 1 || j % 6 == 2 || j % 6 == 6) && ( i % 6 == 3 || i % 6 == 4 || i % 6 == 5 ) )
  cout << " ";
  else if( j % 6 == 0 || j % 6 == 1 || j % 6 == 2 || j % 6 == 6) 
  cout << "*";
  
  else if( i % 6 == 3 || i % 6 == 4 || i % 6 == 5 ) 
  cout << "*";
  
  else
  cout << " ";  '     Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: @Kenny Since you already got it your way, let me give you a tip for the future...If you use integer division, you can do `(j/3)%2` to collapse all 3 of your mod checks ;) Congratulations on figuring out a way to push through tho!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 27;
    int y = 27;

    string res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0, c = '*'; j < x; ++j, c = '*') {
            if (((j / 3) & 1) ^ ((i / 3) & 1))
                c = ' ';

            res += (char)c;
        }

        res += '\n';
    }

    cout << res;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```